# ZeroMQ PHP Timeout

Tags: php, timeout, request, zeromq

I have a problem with my PHP script communicating through ZeroMQ with a PHP Daemon running in the backend and waiting for messages. If maybe the daemon is down the requesting php waits for an endless time. If i reload the page firefox ends in a endless loop and I have to restart apache2 to kill the running request. Especially in the development when the daemon isn't finished, it is really annoying. Do somebody know how i can set a timeout, or just say, skip sennding the request when daemon is not reachable (then send admin a message, server is down and send an error back)?

I tried something like this:

```
$context = new ZMQContext(1);
$req = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);

$req->connect("tcp://localhost:5557");

$read = $write = array();

// Poll socket for a reply, with timeout
$poll = new ZMQPoll();
$poll->add($req, ZMQ::POLL_OUT);
$events = $poll->poll($read, $write, 3000);
       $errors = $poll->getLastErrors();

if($errors)   
  echo "No connection";
else 
  echo "connection";

... $data = ....
$req->send(json_encode($data));
```

2nd Question, I use PHP-Daemon from shaneharter, sometimes when the daemon does not start correctly because of errors or I shut it down with CRTL+C zeromq still reserves the address, when I restart the daemons it throws an exception, this address is already in use.
Can I easily destroy all ZeroMQ connections?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to poll just to sent a simple message.  I think a `PUSH` socket will serve you better.  Set a reasonable linger value and this will attempt to send a message to the `PULL` socket counterpart, whether it's listening or not.

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$socket = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$socket->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_LINGER, 2000);
$socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5557");
$socket->send($data);
```

Comment: Do you know how to set timeout with this example? I tried SOCKOPT_SNDTIMEO but it doesn't work if server is off.